# How to open "Add contact" UI on windows phone 8.1 and higher

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

when trying to use,  "Value does not fall within the expected range" is being thrown on wp8.1. I have added the contacts capability in the app manifest.
    Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation.ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync(ContactStoreSystemAccessMode.ReadOnly,ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode.ReadOnly)

Comment: For the exception, you need to make sure the new contact is on your device and try cleaning your project and rebuild it to see if it persists. You might as well share your sample code so that I can reproduce your issue. To create your own contact Store, you may refer to [custom contact Store API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207024(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Creatingoropeningacontactstore).

Comment: contactStore = await Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation.ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync(ContactStoreSystemAccessMode.ReadWrite,ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode.ReadOnly); StoredContact contact = new StoredContact(contactStore); var createNewContact = await contact.GetPropertiesAsync(); createNewContact.Add(KnownContactProperties.FamilyName, value.userSearchDetail.displayName); createNewContact.Add(KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone, value.userSearchDetail.mobileNum1); await contact.SaveAsync();

Comment: further, i am following the customContactStore because i am unable to find a way to save contacts directly to people hub app (outlook/google) by openin g"add contact to outlook"/"add contact to google" UI on wp8.1 (i am on winrt)